# IS MP short run question

Tags: macroeconomics

I was attempting a past paper question regarding the short run model, specifically IS-MP, although the solutions for the questions have not been made available. I'm having some difficulty understanding these questions. Would someone be able to find the solutions so that I can learn how to solve similar questions in the future? It would be greatly appreciated

[image]

a's =  constant fraction of (potential) output b = interest sensitivity of short-run output, c(bar) = MPC out of current income, Y(bar) = potential output, g = the extent of stabilization i.e. how strongly
government spending responds to fluctuations in SR output , R = real interest rate, r(bar) =  long run real interest rate

I'm particularly confused about c(bar) = g

Comment: This might help: https://www.karlwhelan.com/Macro2/slides-1.pdf